# sublimetext3でgitgutterが動作しない

Tags: windows, git, sublimetext

[Package Control:Install Package]より[gitgutter]をインストールするも、編集した行に印がつきません。

[image: 編集前][image: 編集後]

なぜでしょうか。gitgutter:support infoとフォルダのパスは下の画像通りです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

動作環境: Windows10, Surface Pro3

追記：また、c:\~\packages\の中にGitGutterフォルダがなかったので、参考サイト

http://jisaacks.github.io/GitGutter/install/

の下にあるwindowsのコマンドを打って作成しました。。。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 機械翻訳したような記事ですが、色々載っているので、参考に調べてみてください。[GitGutter – gutのgit diffを見るための崇高なテキスト2/3プラグイン](https://githubja.com/jisaacks/gitgutter)

Comment: @kunif 　ありがとうございます。一通り読み、gitgutterの有効か無効かの確認とバイナリの設定を行いましたが改善せずでした。時間の無駄なので諦めます！！！

Comment: 一番参考になった所はここです！https://github.com/jisaacks/GitGutter/issues/152

Comment: 単なる確認ですが、test_gitgutter.pyはgitリポジトリ内に位置しているファイルですか？git管理している範囲外にあるファイルの場合、gitgutterは反応しません。